# IntelliJ column code formatting

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I am trying to change up the IntelliJ code formatting options to improve the clarity and readability of my code. Two problems I have come across are the following:

1) Creating columns in an array. What I have:

```
private int[][] c = new int[][]{
        {1, 2, 3},
        {100, 200, 300}    
};
```

What I would want:

```
private int[][] c = new int[][]{
        {  1,   2,   3},
        {100, 200, 300}    
};
```

---

2) Aligning parenthesis on multiple lines in binary operations. What I have:

```
final int argb = (red << 0) |
                 (green << 8) |
                 (blue << 16) |
                 (alpha << 24);
```

What I would want:

```
final int argb = (red   <<  0) |
                 (green <<  8) |
                 (blue  << 16) |
                 (alpha << 24);
```

---

If anyone knows of any way this can be done, that would be greatly appreciated. I did not see any options available that seemed to have worked. Maybe there is a weird combination I need. I can provide the current Code Style settings I have. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a plugin for that, called [Tabifier](https://java.net/projects/tabifier), available in the default plugin repository. It haasn't been updated in 3 years, but it seems to still work.

It has extensive configuration and does a lot of controversial layouts, so I recommend turning most of its features off at first, and then slowly enable ones that you need.

The main downside is that the default Reformat Code action ignores whatever Tabifier did, so you would have to manually retabulate chunks of code from time to time

Comment: Is there any way in IntelliJ to make it automatically run the Tabifier? This seems like it would work perfectly if that's possible.

Comment: I don't think so, it doesn't even do ordinary reformat automatically.

Comment: Well I mean like: you press `ctrl+shift+L` to reformat, then it automatically runs the tabifier.

Comment: You can record a macro and assign it to whatever keyboard shortcut you like.